# The button "Add" a Scheduled task does nothing?

Tags: nexus

When I click the "Add" button in the Scheduled Task section to add a scheduled task, nothing happens (the button is enabled). Tested in Chrome, FF en Safari on mac (latest versions)

I am using the "war" edition, running under tomcat 8.
Neither the nexus log file or the tomcat catalina.out log file is containing any nexus error. All the logging looks ok.
I am logged in as a user with the Nexus Administrator role with all Admin privileges. 
Tomcat runs behind Apache and are connected through AJP Proxy.
Apparently Nexus uses the apache Basic credentials, as they are the same and when I logout in Nexus, the page refreshed and I am logged in again.

I upgraded to the latest nexus version 2.11.2-06, but that made no difference.
I thought it might be because I use the free community edition, but don't think that is the reason.
My installation contains a "remove old snapshots" task that runs fine.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine. I am a bit concerned that your Nexus is not working fully though since you are using the unsupported war file running it on Tomcat.

Another question to figure out will be if this problem occurs in all browsers or just a specific one.

You can contact us [in the Nexus community](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/lists-live-chat-and-other-resources/) for more detailed help.

Comment: Tanks for your reply. Just added info about the tested browser. Just tested in Chrome, FF en Safari and all the same: pressing the Add button: nothing happens :( No idea why. What is the workaround to add tasks (in Db/config directly?)

Comment: Did you check if Nexus boots up and starts okay in the log?

Comment: No strange exception/error there, neither in catalina.out or nexus log file. Just restarted again to be sure, and added the info above.

Comment: Just to be certain.. you are logged in as admin?

Comment: Yes, just double checked, I have the "Nexus Administrator role" that contains the privileges: Api-Key access, Admin priv (all), Security Admin Priv (all). There is also a default admin user, but I can't use it as when I perform a logout, and the page refresh, I am logged in again, as it probably use the Apache Basic Auth user login that is the same... (I use Apache AJP Proxy in front of tomcat)